# Change detection not working in component created using createComponent

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a modal service within my Angular application, and I've got some code like this (simplified):

```js
import { ApplicationRef, ElementRef, EnvironmentInjector, Injector,  Renderer2, RendererFactory2, createComponent } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

    constructor(private application: ApplicationRef,
        private injector: Injector,
        private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {

    }

    public show<C>(component: Type<C>) {
        const modalComponent = createComponent(component, {
          environmentInjector: injector.get(EnvironmentInjector),
          elementInjector: injector
        });
        modalComponent.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        modalComponent.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();

        const modalElement: HTMLElement = modalComponent.location.nativeElement;

        const renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
        const ref = this.application.components[0].injector.get(ElementRef);
        renderer.appendChild(ref.nativeElement, modalElement);
    }
}
```

The above code lives in a service, and I use it to display modals as required. It works fine to create and display my component, but it doesn't detect changes:

```js
@Component({
  template: '<div style="background: #fff;"><button (click)="inc(-1)">-</button>{{i}}<button (click)="inc(1)">+</button></div>'
})
export class TestComponent {
  public i = 0;
  inc(value: number): void {
    this.i = this.i + value;
    console.log(i);
  }
}

this.modalService.show(TestComponent);
```

Although I can see the value of `i` increase or decrease as I click the - and + buttons, I don't see it reflected in the rendered value for `i` (`{{i}}`).

If I call `detectChanges()` on `ChangeDetectorRef`, it works as expected, rendering the value for `i` as it changes:

```js
export class TestComponent {
  public i = 0;

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  inc(value: number): void {
    this.i = this.i + value;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

The best solution I've found so far is to use `createComponent` on `ViewContainerRef` instead of `createComponent`, but this means that I need to inject the service into my root component, and then pass in a `ViewContainerRef`:

```js
modalComponent = this.viewContainer.createComponent(component, {
        environmentInjector: injector.get(EnvironmentInjector),
        injector: injector
      });
```

How do I correctly wire up the component so that things like button clicks, etc. update the UI correctly without needing `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` everywhere (which is clearly the wrong approach), and without needing to pass a ViewContainerRef into the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I was on the right track with `ViewContainerRef`. I just needed a way to obtain it. My initial attempt was to inject the service into the root component and then pass in a `ViewContainerRef` from there, using that to call `CreateComponent`.

The solution I've finally come to is simpler and neater. Using `ApplicationRef` injected into the service, you can find the root component and use its injector to get its `ViewContainerRef`:

```js
const viewContainerRef = this.application.components[0].injector.get(ViewContainerRef);
```

Now I can use that to create the component:

```js
const modalComponent = viewContainerRef.createComponent(component, {
  environmentInjector: injector.get(EnvironmentInjector),
  injector: injector
});
modalComponent.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
modalComponent.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
```

And finally the modal component reacts to the UI as you would expect, no `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();` required.